# Manipulating arrays in Java. Stuck on difficult homework task

Tags: java, arrays

I am brand new to Java and am learning it in a programming course this semester. We have a homework assignment due and I am struggling. I appreciate this will be easy for the experienced programmers out there but for me it's a head scratcher. Here's the first question.

> > public int countInRange(int[] data, int lo, int hi)
> >
> > For this, you have to count the number of elements of the array, data, that lie in the range >>lo to hi inclusive, and return the count. For example, if data is the array {1, 3, 2, 5, 8} >>then the call
> >
> > countInRange(data, 2, 5)
> >
> > should return 3 because there are three elements, 3, 2 and 5 that lie in the range 2 .. 5.

And here is what I have done so far:

```
/**
 * Count the number of occurrences of values in an array, R, that is
 * greater than or equal to lo and less than or equal to hi.
 *
 * @param  data  the array of integers
 * @param  lo   the lowest value of the range
 * @param  hi   the highest value of the range
 * @return      the count of numbers that lie in the range lo .. hi
 */
public int countInRange(int[] array, int lo, int hi) {
    int counter = 0; 
    int occurrences = 0;
    while(counter < array.length) {
        if(array[counter] >= lo) {
            occurrences++; 
        }
        counter++;
    }
    return occurrences;
}
```

Comment: Just a tip (not related to your problem). Try to use the for statement to iterate over arrays ;) In Java, there is a enhanced for too (for-each) that is even better in some cases, including yours. Solve the problem and I will post some code ;)

Comment: So: "*What* is the question?"

Comment: Please accept one of the answers as an answer to your question and upvote if it helped you. It is the least you can do when somebody invests time in helping you out. You have asked six questions and received answers to them all, but never  accepted one of them.

Answer (score 6):

```
if(array[counter] >= lo && conditionforhighcheck)
{
//Then only update occurence count
}
```

Because of homework,I didn't type in code. I gave a pointer.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the upper bound check in your if statement.

Answer (score 1):

```
for ( int i = 0; i < array.length; i++ ) {
    if ( array[i] >= lo && array[i] <= hi ) {
        occurrences++;
    }
}
```

Use for statement to iterate an array.

Answer (score 1):

With arrays and Collections in java, you may use a [foreach loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html), and especially when you're learning, "less code" is (usually) easier to understand, because the code that's left is just the important stuff.

On the other hand, if you want to construct your own loop, always use a `for` loop - updating the loop variable within a `while` loop (when it's unnecessary) is considered poor style because it can lead to nasty bugs.

The answer is so simple, it's hardly worth making you work it out from cryptic hints:

```
public int countInRange(int[] array, int lo, int hi) {
    int occurrences = 0;
    for (int element : array) {
        if (element >= lo && element <= hi) {
            occurrences++;
        }
    }
    return occurrences;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much to every one that helped. I have figured it out and have some good suggestions for the future. Cheers!